# Spring Boot Oauth2 and google services api

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have an web application whcih allows only google users and uses `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` to obtain authentication. I want to integrate Google API into my application, but all examples using its onw Oath2 process to authenticate user. How can I reuse existing spring boot google login for interaction with google API services?

Thanks!

Comment: hi there, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client** dependency that allows the client registration for oauth2 providers, but before that it's necessary the **client-id** and **client-secret** provided by your oauth2 provider (such google). [Here's](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) a nice guide of how do that.

Comment: Actually I have already implemented google client to for authentication process. I just want to reuse this for google api interaction (such as Calendar API etc)

Comment: I think what you need is a specific scope or more of them associated with the oauth2 session, so take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes).

Comment: To add more scopes (link above) in your provider config you will need an extra property at `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope` with values (if more than one) separated by comma.

Comment: How did you manage to renew expired tokens? Spring OAuth2 login wont request a resfresh token